# Try to referece a image, but it say it's undefined

Tags: latex, overleaf

```
...wie in der Abbildung: \ref{fig:serviceWorke} zu sehen ist. 

\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{gfx/chapter-2/service-worker-architectur.png}
    \caption{Service Worker Architektur [6] (S.24)}%
    \label{fig:serviceWorker}
\end{figure}
\vspace{0.5cm}
```

Trying to reference a image but it only display a "??".

That's the Error: Reference `fig:serviceWorke' on page 11 undefined on input line 126.

I don't get the Problem.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo: `fig:serviceWorker` vs. `fig:serviceWorke`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

...wie in der Abbildung: \ref{fig:serviceWorker} zu sehen ist. 


\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Service Worker Architektur [6] (S.24)}%
    \label{fig:serviceWorker}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @Patrickj You're welcome! (I think we've all been there :) )